# How to find rows where the same column has only the same another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose following table:

```
Name Age Occupation
Alex 20  Student
Alex 20  Seller
Alex 20  Minister
Liza 19  Student
Liza 20  Volunteer
Liza 21  HR partner
```

I want to find names which have only (and only) 20 in age column. So from this table I want to get all "Alex" rows and no "Liza" rows at all.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Group By` and `Having` clause. Try this way

```
select Name
from table
group by Name
having count(case when Age = 20 then 1 end) = count(*)
```

`count(case when Age = 20 then 1 end)` counts only when `age = 20` if it is equal to total count then the name has only `20` as age.

Answer (score 3):

Just one another way:

```
select Name
from table
group by Name
having min(Age) = 20 and max(Age) = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is using `NOT IN()`:

```
SELECT Name, Age, Occupation
FROM YourTable
WHERE Age = 20
AND Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM YourTable WHERE Age <> 20)
```